# Phase Diagrams - Hypereutectic, pro-eutectic phase

Tags: phase-diagram

While designing some questions for my undergraduate class, I came across a scenario that is having me scratch my head.

I am using the Cu-Ag phase diagram and arbitrarily selected Co = 90 wt.% Ag. My math and tie lines are attached. What I can't figure out is if my total beta phase is 91%, how can my pro-eutectic beta be almost 94%?

From what I understand: total beta = eutectic beta + pro-eutectic beta.

It was suggested that accurate measurement of the x-axis is mandatory, but is it really that crucial in this case or is something else going on?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What is the issue? You have different temperatures with different tie lines to different things. If the eutectic point were further towards Cu, your $\beta$ percentage would be even higher, and that would not impact the balance of $\alpha$ vs $\beta$ at the lower temperature.

Comment: Hi Jon, my issue is that if I were to calculate the pro-eutectic phase in this case, the value would be 93.7%. However, my total beta phase is only 91% using the tie line. I have been told that even small differences in numbers can have a large effect on weight fractions. My assumption that the left of the tie line is 0 may be incorrect.

Comment: For fun, consider a 91.2 at% Ag composition. At 779C, the eutectic, the entire sample would be pure $\beta$ phase right there at the point on the Ag solidus line. Dropping below that means nucleating the $\alpha$ copper phase, taking some of the silver with it. You go from one phase to two - the amount of phase one must decrease. Trust the phase diagram, and wrap your understanding around it.

Comment: This is perfect - I never thought of it that way. Thank you!